# slower parallel compute and write to shared numpy array using joblib

Tags: numpy, joblib

I would like to use joblib to perform parallel computation on numpy array. A minimal example of working code is below:

```
import time
import math
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def compute(i, I):
   I[i] = math.sqrt(i)

N = 10000
I = np.zeros(N)

t = time.time()
for i in range(N):
   compute(i, I)
print("sequential time = %fs" % (time.time() - t))
print('norm = %f' % np.linalg.norm(I))

t = time.time()
Parallel(n_jobs=4, backend="threading")(delayed(compute)(i, I) for i in range(N))
print("parallel time = %fs" % (time.time() - t))
print('norm = %f' % np.linalg.norm(I))
```

The results on my computer shows that the computation is correct, but the parallel time is much slower than the sequential time:

```
sequential time = 0.002715s
norm = 7070.714250
parallel time = 0.468109s
norm = 7070.714250
```

I'm sure there is no race condition using threading mode in the above example. What could be the reason of this problem?

Comment: I'm sure you don't need me to comment this, but numpy already has code optimisation for vectorial calculations. In your case, `I = np.sqrt(np.arange(N))` will solve the calculation in 22 us, more than a hundred times faster than sequential time.

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi the question is actually on the joblib capability to modify the numpy array in parallel. The actual code is not simple sqrt but array of more complicated operations, and involve more than one numpy array.

Comment: I figured so. But I also thought that the comment on the correct use of numpy could be useful to someone out there. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not doing enough work in `compute` to mask the parallel computing overheads. I modified your code slightly to add `time.sleep(1)` within `compute` and changed `N` from `10000` to `10`.

I get

```
sequential time = 10.042081s
norm = 6.708204
parallel time = 3.036538s
norm = 6.708204
```

I know it is probably not optimally parallel, but it's a start.

Modified code:

```
import time
import math
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def compute(i, I):
   time.sleep(1) 
   I[i] = math.sqrt(i)

N = 10
I = np.zeros(N)

t = time.time()
for i in range(N):
   compute(i, I)
print("sequential time = %fs" % (time.time() - t))
print('norm = %f' % np.linalg.norm(I))

t = time.time()
Parallel(n_jobs=4, backend="threading")(delayed(compute)(i, I) for i in range(N))
print("parallel time = %fs" % (time.time() - t))
print('norm = %f' % np.linalg.norm(I))
```

Comment: This is not the purpose of the question. The numpy array is very large (N>>10000). Put up N=1000000 gives the same problem.

Comment: I think that within each call to ```compute```, you need to do enough work to mask the overhead of launching the parallel job.  It doesn't matter if your ```N``` is large.